# "Specified cast is not valid" in LinqToSql query

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, casting, enums, .net

**Specified cast is not valid**.

OrderItemState is *enum*.

```
IEnumerable<OrderItemState> states = ...;
IEnumerable<byte> stateIds = Enumerable.Cast<byte>(states);

List<OrderEntry> entries =
  (from m in dc.OrderItemMotions
   where stateIds.Contains(m.OrderItemStateId)
   select ...).ToList();
```

Why?

Part of StackTrace:

> at System.Linq.Enumerable.d__b1`1.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.<OfTypeIterator>d__aa`1.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
>      at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitContains(Expression sequence, Expression value)
>      at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(MethodCallExpression mc)
>      at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression node)
>      at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.Visit(Expression node)
>      at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitWhere(Expression sequence, LambdaExpression predicate)
>      at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(MethodCallExpression mc)
>      at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression node)
>      at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitWhere(Expression sequence, LambdaExpression predicate)
>      at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(MethodCallExpression mc)
>      at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression node)
>      at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitGroupBy(Expression sequence, LambdaExpression keyLambda, LambdaExpression elemLambda, LambdaExpression resultSelector)
>      at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(MethodCallExpression mc)
>      at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression node)
>      at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitJoin(Expression outerSequence, Expression innerSequence, LambdaExpression outerKeySelector, LambdaExpression innerKeySelector, LambdaExpression resultSelector)
>      at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(MethodCallExpression mc)
>      at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression node)
>      at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.ConvertOuter(Expression node)
>      at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.BuildQuery(Expression query, SqlNodeAnnotations annotations)
>      at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
>      at System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
>      at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)

Comment: You sure the backing type of the enum is in fact a `byte`? If not, you will need to do a 'double cast' eg `(byte)(int) enumvalue`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't cast an `enum` to a `byte` without data loss so the cast will fail (`enum` is an `int` under the hood).

But you can define an `enum` to use a `byte` under-the-hood if you only want values in the range 0-255 using:

```
public enum Values : byte { val1, val2};
```

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If the base-type of the enum is an int (which is default), you can cast the enum to an int.

If the base-type of the enum is a byte, you can cast the enum to a byte.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely one of your enum values contain a value that can't fit into a `byte`.

Assume this code:

```
IEnumerable<MyEnum> arr = new MyEnum[] { MyEnum.first, MyEnum.second };
var bytes = Enumerable.Cast<byte>(arr);
foreach (var b in bytes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(b);
}
```

It will work if:

```
enum MyEnum:byte { first = 120, second };
```

It won't work if:

```
enum MyEnum:long { first = 1204, second };
```